# NgRx: How to use services in meta-reducers?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dependency-injection, ionic4, ngrx

I use a custom middleware ([meta-reducer](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/metareducers)) to print my `ngrx-store` each time an action is dipatched. I wrote my middleware directly inside `app.module.ts` (where else should I put it ?):

**app.module.ts**

```js
// ...imports

// ...

// FIXME:
/**
 * console.log action and state(before action) each time an action is dipatched
 * @param reducer reducer
 */
export function debug(reducer: ActionReducer<AppState, Actions>): ActionReducer<AppState, Actions> {

    const logger = new LoggerService(); ////////////// ERROR \\\\\\\\\\\\\\

    return (state, action) => {

        logger.storeInfo('ACTION', action);
        logger.storeInfo('STATE', state);

        return reducer(state, action);
    };
}

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<any>[] = [
    debug,
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, LoggerServiceComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        // ...
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot(), // Connects RouterModule with StoreModule
    ],
    providers: [
       // ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

There is an error because my `LoggerService` has a store injected (because I want all my logs to be stored in `ngx-store`. **But I can't access the store neither !**. Furthermore, I'm sure that's not the good way of accessing the singleton instance of a service...

- Should I put my meta reducer inside a class, and then accessing the function of that class, but how do I do it ?
- Is there a general method to access any service, like `SomeClass.getServiceInstance(type)` ?
- Do you have other ideas on how to do it ?

## [EDIT 1] - using `META_REDUCERS` (1st try - failing)

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { LoggerService } from './services/logger.service';
import { AppState, Actions } from './app.state';
import { StoreModule, MetaReducer, ActionReducer, META_REDUCERS } from '@ngrx/store';

/**
 * Injects a `LoggerService` inside a `MetaReducer`
 * @param logger a service that allows to log and store console.log() messages
 * @returns a `MetaReducer`
 */
function debugFactory(logger: LoggerService): MetaReducer<AppState> {
    return (reducer: ActionReducer<AppState, Actions>): ActionReducer<AppState, Actions> => {
        return (state, action) => {

           logger.storeInfo('ACTION', action);
           logger.storeInfo('STATE', state);

           return reducer(state, action);
        };
    };
}

/**
 * Injects a LoggerService inside the debug `MetaReducer` function
 * @param logger a service that allows to log and store console.log() messages
 * @returns A list of `MetaReducer`
 */
export function getMetaReducers(logger: LoggerService): MetaReducer<AppState>[] {
    return [debugFactory(logger)];
}

const reducers = {
    layout: layoutReducer,
    preferences: preferencesReducer,
    router: routerReducer,
    debug: debugReducer,
};

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent ],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        // ...
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot(), // Connects RouterModule with StoreModule
    ],
    providers: [
        // ...
        {
            provide: META_REDUCERS,
            deps: [LoggerService],
            useFactory: getMetaReducers,
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This should work, according to the document but I have the following error at runtime:

```
TypeError: "fn is not a function"
```

Corresponding to this function (in the njrx-store library):

```js
/**
 * @param {...?} functions
 * @return {?}
 */
function compose(...functions) {
    return (/**
     * @param {?} arg
     * @return {?}
     */
    function (arg) {
        if (functions.length === 0) {
            return arg;
        }
        /** @type {?} */
        const last = functions[functions.length - 1];
        /** @type {?} */
        const rest = functions.slice(0, -1);
        return rest.reduceRight((/**
         * @param {?} composed
         * @param {?} fn
         * @return {?}
         */
        (composed, fn) => {
             return fn(composed) // <----- HERE
        }), last(arg));
    });
}
```

In the debugger, it shows that the function array (`...functions`) contains some functions and one array, which I suspect is the result of the method `getMetaReducers`. I suspect either the example is wrong or there is a problem with the implementation of the `compose` method.

Tell me if you see any wrong things in my code.

## [EDIT 2] - using `USER_PROVIDED_META_REDUCERS` as mentioned in answer (2nd try - failing)

**code that have been edited**

```js
// OLD

    providers: [
        // ...
        {
            provide: META_REDUCERS,
            deps: [LoggerService],
            useFactory: getMetaReducers,
            multi: true,
        },
    ],

// NEW

    providers: [
        // ...
        {
            provide: USER_PROVIDED_META_REDUCERS,
            deps: [LoggerService],
            useFactory: getMetaReducers,
        },
    ],
```

It seems that my `LoggerService` is either not correctly passed nor initialized because I have now this error:

```
core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'storeInfo' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8102/main.js:636:20
    at http://localhost:8102/vendor.js:109798:20
    at computeNextEntry (http://localhost:8102/vendor.js:108628:21)
    at recomputeStates (http://localhost:8102/vendor.js:108681:15)
    at http://localhost:8102/vendor.js:109029:26
    at ScanSubscriber.StoreDevtools.liftedAction$.pipe.Object.state [as accumulator] (http://localhost:8102/vendor.js:109081:38)
    at ScanSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:8102/vendor.js:120261:27)
    at ScanSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8102/vendor.js:120254:25)
    at ScanSubscriber.next (http://localhost:8102/vendor.js:114391:18)
    at WithLatestFromSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8102/vendor.js:122330:34)
```

if I comment those lines:

```js
        logger.storeInfo('ACTION', action);
        logger.storeInfo('STATE', state);
```

No exception will be thrown, but my logger won't work either.

But at least the store configures itself correcly, the problem now is just that the LoggerService is either not correctly passed nor initialized. I guess I'm still doing something wrong

Comment: Most likely the "undefined" issue is related to a circular dependency between your store and logger service, as during the creation of the store, angular´s IOC container will try to instantiate a logger service, which depends on the store, before the creation of the store is finalized. You could solve this by "lazily" accessing the store in the logger service by injecting the `Injector` into it and defining a getter property for the store, something like `private get() store{return this.injector.get(Store);}`

Comment: BTW, your logic is flawed. Dispatching an action in the meta-reducer through your logger service will lead your app to an infinite state of reduce -> dispatch -> reduce -> dispatch..... I should had realized this earlier.

Comment: Apologies, I saw your answer covered it perfectly - old comment removed. I will add a further comment to help those like myself to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try by injecting meta-reducers using the `META_REDUCERS` token as [documented](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/recipes/injecting#injecting-meta-reducers):

(**HEADS UP**: as of 24.Sept the docs are a bit misleading, the factory method return type should be `MetaReducer` and not `MetaReducer[]`. Check [this example in the codebase](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/8.3.0/modules/store/src/runtime_checks.ts#L85))

```
export debugFactory(logger: LoggerService): MetaReducer<AppState> {
 return (reducer: ActionReducer<AppState, Actions>): ActionReducer<AppState, Actions> => {
    return (state, action) => {

        logger.storeInfo('ACTION', action);
        logger.storeInfo('STATE', state);

        return reducer(state, action);
    };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: META_REDUCERS,
      deps: [LoggerService],
      useFactory: debugFactory,
      multi: true
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Update:**

[Since v8](https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v8#meta_reducers-token) you can use the `ÙSER_PROVIDED_META_REDUCERS` token:

```
export function getMetaReducers(logger: LoggerService): MetaReducer<AppState>[] {
 return [debugFactory(logger)];
}

providers: [
  {
     provide: USER_PROVIDED_META_REDUCERS,
     deps: [LoggerService],
     useFactory: getMetaReducers
  },
],
```

In this case the provided factory method has to return `MetaReducer[]`. Both "library" and "user" provided meta-reducers are combined into one collection in [this function](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/8.3.0/modules/store/src/store_module.ts#L282).

You will most likely hit a cyclic dependency between your store and logger service, as during the creation of the store, angular´s IOC container will try to instantiate a logger service, which depends on the store, before the creation of the store is finalized. You could solve this by "lazily" accessing the store in the logger service by injecting the Injector into it and defining a getter property for the store, something like:

```
private get() store{return this.injector.get(Store);}

ctor(private readonly injector: Injector){}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems it's getting me toward the good direction but unfortunately my code still will not work. I updated my question with my new code.

Comment: Could you setup a minimal project for me to debug?

Comment: I can give you the repo of the full project for the moment, I will try to setup a minimal project tomorrow
https://github.com/davidalvarezr/gallereddit

Comment: @DavidAlvarez Ill take a look

Comment: Here is the minimal project: https://github.com/davidalvarezr/minimalGallereddit. You can directly run it in the browser using `ionic serve`. It throws the same error as my main project. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I also added a branch `with-store-devtools` if you want to directly use it with the Redux DevTools browser extension to inspect the state of the app. Also, the project is generating the same error, which is cool, but then the Redux DevTools won't work. To make it work just comment the provider object

Comment: Here is the the [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/github/davidalvarezr/minimalGallereddit) if you don't want to pull the repo

Comment: I have updated my question with `USER_PROVIDED_META_REDUCERS`

Comment: For those who would like to see this in action, using the above [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/github/davidalvarezr/minimalGallereddit):
app.module.ts:
Change `META_REDUCERS ` to `USER_PROVIDED_META_REDUCERS` and remove `multi: true`
logger.service.ts:
Change the constructor to the following:
`constructor(private readonly injector: Injector) {}
private get store() { return this.injector.get(Store)}`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo yes it does, sorry. I was only trying to condense it into an easy to follow set of steps with the example given. Thank you very much for your help. This was a head-scratcher.

Comment: Heads up! If you want to do metareducer dependency injection at a feature level and can't find how, it's hidden in the docs [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/recipes/injecting#injecting-feature-config)